# Deleting the folder being watched by FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, directory

I'd like to create an application where instead of only watching a root hierarchy folder, ... I watch each folder individually (with watch subfolders turned off)

However, I can't seem to be able to get the delete logic right. I want to be able to delete any folder in the hierarchy, either internally within the application, or externally, say via windows explorer.

When I try either of these, it appears I get locking issues, as the delete commands fail to execute.

If I disable the watching, then everything seems to work. So I'm assuming the problem is trying to delete a folder that is being watched.

Is there anyway of getting around this? I'd ideally like the fileSystemWatcher to automatically stop watching when the folder its watching has been deleted.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    fsw1 = new FileSystemWatcher()
    {
        Path = "Folder",
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
        IncludeSubdirectories = false,
        Filter = "",
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };

    fsw1.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileSystemItemDeleted);

    fsw2 = new FileSystemWatcher()
    {
        Path = "Folder/Folder",
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
        IncludeSubdirectories = false,
        Filter = "",
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };

    fsw2.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileSystemItemDeleted);
}

protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

    //fsw1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    //fsw2.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

    System.IO.Directory.Delete("Folder", true);
}

void OnFileSystemItemDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

}

FileSystemWatcher fsw1, fsw2;
```

Comment: Did you mean stopping watching when it's about to be deleted?

Comment: Just dispose the watcher first, no point in keeping it going.  Watching the folder getting deleted requires watching the parent directory.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I guess so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using fsw1 and fsw2 in order to watch data of any type that might get deleted at any point of time.

Although, i do not see the point of creating a FSW for each folder, here is an answer that might help:

In order to watch for the folders themselves, you need to create a FSW for each folder you would like to observe.

You can then setup the NotifyFilter of the FSW to DirectoryName as follows: `folderSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilter.DirectoryName`

see an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336637/net-filesystemwatcher-was-it-a-file-or-a-directory).

So one of the FSWs tell you that a folder is deleted, you can then stop, dispose or do whatever to the FSW that is watching that deleted folder.

I did not try that out, but this is how i would have done it, i guess...