# C# how to check local folder for new files and keep a counter

Tags: c#, lambda, system.io.file

I am currently trying to keep a counter on c# on a local file folder for new files that are created.

I have two sub directories to CD and LP that I have to keep checking.

Maybe some pseudo code might help

```
        static int CDcounter = 0;
        static int LPcounter = 0;
        public void returnFileCount()
        {
            //Location of Files
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Data\LotData");


            //if file sub directory = cd go in and check for new files
            //if new files pop up in cd CDcounter ++ same for LP
        }
```

Comment: `files.Length` will give you current count of files in `LotData` folder, if new file added then this code should be executed again then only you will get latest count of files in that folder. This is what you are expecting?

Comment: Shouldn't it be files.Count? Just wondering

Comment: `files.Count()` will work as `Count()` is an extension method

Comment: I just did the below and it still doesn't work
            `file = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Data\LotData\CD");
            CDcounter = file.Count();`

Comment: I just realized I need to keep count on folders not files p.s

Comment: Duplicate of [Number of folder inside a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996443/number-of-folder-inside-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer guys

```
//Counter for directories
CDcounter = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Data\LotData\CD").GetDirectories().Length;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5996574/7144746

Answer (score 0):

You could use Directory.GetDirectories to get the initial count of directories.

```
CDcounter = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Data\LotData\CD").Length
```

Then you can use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) and filter only for directories.

```
        dirWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        dirWatcher.Path = @"C:\Data\LotData\CD";
        dirWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        dirWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

You can subscribe to the Created and Deleted events to keep a count of directories.

[This answer details how to use FileSystemWatcher for directories and files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337684/5092371)